# Нужен совет по client-server

Tags: windows, сеть, сокет, сетевое-программирование

Пишу клиент-серверное ПО. Интересует такой момент, при передаче информации на сервер. Можно ли узнать адрес т.е. ip куда передается информация при условии, что используется шифрование трафика. Просто не хотелось чтобы какой нибудь "вундеркинд" потом вывел из строя сервер. Зная IP его.

P.S. Можно ли подменить или скрыть этот IP. Если не возможно?

Comment: ip приема невозможно скрыть. Боитесь DDOS - Cloudfare в помощь

Comment: Против DDoS - сервисы anti-DDoS. Защита системы против взлома (отключение всех лишних сервисов, на SSH использование ключей и запрет использование паролей) И лишний раз пересмотр авторизации и доступ на сервер из приложения.

Answer (score 3):

Вы же трафик шифруете, а не адрес. А если зашифруете адрес, то куда передавать? Помните классическое "на деревню дедушке"? Там тоже адрес зашифрован.

Если же серьезно, то адреса сервера и клиента всегда открыты и известны, в противном случае никакого общения не получилось бы. И знания IP адреса недостаточно для выведения из строя сервера.

Адрес, кстати, можно узнать не только анализом пакетов, в Интернете полно сканеров, которые ищут открытые порты серверов. Например, как показывает опыт, достаточно открыть миру порт 22 буквально на 5-10 минут, чтобы туда начали ломиться какие-то роботы с подбором паролей.

Comment: @user317720, Шифруют паролем - где будете держать пароль для расшифровки? Там же, в exe (ну а где еще)? Обычный юзер и без шифрования ничего не вскроет, а хакер от вашей "защиты" будет смеяться. Придумайте какой-нибудь другой метод, понадежнее.

Comment: @user317720, шифруют ключом. Для того, чтобы программа выполнялась, ее надо сначала расшифровать. Где брать ключ? Ответ: он должен быть в том же .exe, больше его взять неоткуда. Шифрование .exe - это всего лишь имитация с целью запутать взломщика. Причем любая защита .exe успешно вскрывается, посмотрите как быстро взламываются новые программы и игры. Вы готовы поместить в такой .exe пароль к вашему серверу в расчете, что тупой взломщик вашу защиту не осилит? Я бы не рискнул, ну а вам виднее.

Comment: @user317720, когда вы придумываете способ защиты, не надо упираться в незначащие моменты типа "*расшифровывает в ОЗУ*". Какая разница куда расшифровывает. Задумываться надо о главном. А главный вопрос здесь: "*где я буду брать ключ для расшифровки данных и сможет ли взломщик взять его там же?*". Ответ на этот вопрос сразу и покажет чего стоит ваш метод.

Comment: @user317720, я не знаю вашей конкретной задачи, что я могу предложить? Да и вопрос этот слишком сложный, чтобы в двух словах что-то сказать. Могу только сказать, что вы пошли в неправильном направлении. Думайте как построить обмен данными таким образом, чтобы ничего не зависело от секретных ключей или тайных знаний, которые просто некуда прятать. Хорошая система должна работать надежно даже при условии, что хакеру известно о ней абсолютно все. Посмотрите как устроены подобные системы, примеры же наверняка есть.

Comment: @user317720, не могу. Во-первых, NDA, а во-вторых не факт что мои примеры вам подойдут, я делал немного другие вещи. У вас же есть какие-то конкуренты? Посмотрите как у них устроено. Пусть детали неизвестны, но принцип наверняка можно понять.

Comment: @user317720, блин, ну какая парочка примеров - это что, типовая задача из учебника? Это нужно по конкретному ТЗ разрабатывать протокол, а я между прочим, даже толком не знаю что вы вообще хотите сделать. Это вообще вопрос не формата SO - спросил, получил ответ, задача решена. Я вам дал совет как это делается правильно - не использовать пароли и шифрование, а делать устойчивый к взлому протокол. Посмотрите на любую онлайновую игру, как-то же они обходятся без хранения пароля от сервера в exe.